# Is there a data type whose size is 4 Bytes in x86 and 8 bytes in x64?

Tags: c++, types, cross-platform

I am trying to find a data type whose size is changed according to the application architecture (x86, x64).
As I know, `int` and `long` are 4 bytes in the two architectures (x86, x64), and `long long` is only 8 bytes.
Also, there is `size_t`, but I think that is not a cross-platform data type.

**Is there a data type that is resized according to the application architecture and at the same time a cross-platform?**

Comment: `std::(u)intptr_t` in `<cstdint>`

Comment: `void*` (you didn't specify the requirement is for the data type to be an integral one.) Btw: please specify "cross platform". The `std::size_t` type alias is available via any standard library supporting C++17.

Comment: `std::ptrdiff_t`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you, but is that data type only suitable with pointers or you can use it with any numerical data types?

Comment: @LionKing `std::(u)intptr_t` are pointer-sized integers, and the size of a pointer changes based on architecture.

Comment: See also [Fundamental types - Data models](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: Seems like a straightforward case for a typedef, with appropriate definitions for the various supported platforms.

Comment: `size_t` is supported across platforms, but it is not always consistent. I've seen compilers from different vendors implement `size_t` with different sizes on the same architecture. Sometimes 4 bytes, sometimes 8 bytes. I tend to stay away from `size_t`, but the standard library uses it pretty heavily.

Comment: Is `int` the same size on `x86` and `x64`?  My understand is that `int` has a minimum size, but on many processors, `int` is the processor's word (register) size.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Pretty much always 32 bit, I believe.  (It's kinda historical - a lot of older code tends to assume it).

Comment: For what purpose do you need this type? There are specific types for specific purposes in the standard library. You should just use them accordingly.

Comment: long is 32bit on windows and 64bit on linux on 64bit cpus. std::size_t is likely what you need.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `char` is usually 8bit, then `short` is 2 bytes and `int` 4 bytes. If you make `int` 8 bytes then you have no standard type left for 4 byte integers. Also 4 byte values often have faster opcodes for `mul` and more so for `div`. Or a mixed 32bit / 64bit opcode the compiler can take advantage of. So having a half register type on 64bit cpus makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Have you seen the new C++ and C types:  `uint32_t, int32_t`.  These are standard types, thus there are standard types left for 4 byte integers.  The preferred paradigm is to use `uintXX_t` and `intXX_t` when a specific width is needed.  Otherwise, the other types are by minimum range, not by byte width.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews They are rather new. Only since the last millenium, you know, and aliases to the legacy type series `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` I was talking about. `int` being 4 byte, `long long` being 8 byte and `long` being 4/8 byte depending on weather you are on windows is older than `stdint.h` from C99.

Answer (score 1):

I think the type you're looking for is `void *`, i.e. `sizeof(void *)` will be 4 for x86 and 8 for x86_64 as you would expect.

Try it for a few different compilers and arches on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/h9dr33G6v). There are caveats of course. Running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit platform is still possible with some OSes, but depending on what you're trying to do, this could still give you the desired result.

Comment: `sizeof(void*)` is not a type. It's a value.

Comment: Sorry @PeteBecker, maybe I should have been more careful in my wording. `void *` is a type. `sizeof(void *)` will give OP the 4 on x86 and 8 on x86_64 requested. I'm surprised by the confusion but I'll go ahead and edit the response.